# How do I only add an entry to a List<> when it's not already in the list?

Tags: c#

I've tried to find an answer to this but can't seem to find anything specific. I have found answered questions on checking for distinct entries but I am more concerned with one field.

This is my code:

```
        PeopleLocationsForUserRoot peoplelocationforuser = await WebDataAccess.GetPeopleLocationForUser(UserInfoRepository.GetUserName(), _locationID);

        List<LocationPeople> users = new List<LocationPeople>();

        foreach (var user in peoplelocationforuser.locationPeople)
        {
            user.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;

            users.Add(user);
        }
```

As I add an entry to the users list, I want to only add it, if a matching FullName entry doesn't already exist in the list (e.g. there can't be 2 x John Smith).

Comment: *if a matching FullName entry doesn't already exist in the list* => `if (!users.Any(u => u.FullName == user.FullName))`

Comment: Then I'd recommend you simply check *"if a matching FullName entry doesn't already exist"* before you add it.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I'm essentially asking how to do that.

Comment: @connersz You are (or at least your code suggests) familiar with for-each loops and Lists. What's stopping you from checking if the List contains an entry that fulfills a certain condition (`if (x.FullName == xy)`)? Why don't you just **do it**? Ivan's Linq query is the easiest way to it it, but I don't see why you can't figure it out yourself. Which step is missing? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use some kind of user id to identify users? In the real world, it's very possible for two people to have the same name...

Comment: Are you sure you want a `List`? your requirements sound more like a *set*.

Answer (score 1):

```
PeopleLocationsForUserRoot peoplelocationforuser = await WebDataAccess.GetPeopleLocationForUser(UserInfoRepository.GetUserName(), _locationID);

List<LocationPeople> users = new List<LocationPeople>();

foreach (var user in peoplelocationforuser.locationPeople)
{
    user.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;

    if(!user.contains(x => x.FullName == user.FullName)
    {
       users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Something like this could work. There may be a more efficient way though.

Or you could try and use the DistinctBy from MoreLinq. Just add all full names and at the end call this method.

```
users = users.DistinctBy(m => m.FullName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a [Dictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) first:

```
PeopleLocationsForUserRoot peoplelocationforuser = await WebDataAccess.GetPeopleLocationForUser(UserInfoRepository.GetUserName(), _locationID);

// create a temporary dictionary
var tempDic = new Dictionary<string, LocationPeople>();

foreach (var user in peoplelocationforuser.locationPeople)
{
    user.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;

    // check the dictionary before adding
    if (!tempDic.ContainsKey(user.FullName))
    {
        tempDoc.Add(user);
    }
}

// once I have my dictionary, I can make a list
var users = new List<LocationPeople>(tempDic.Values);
```

Comment: Changing the entire type is great and all but is a pretty breaking change depending on the rest of OPs program.

Comment: @Equalsk breaking?  I create the OP List object at the end of the method. How is that breaking?

Comment: Oh, my apologies, obviously my coffee has not kicked in. I'll go back to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create list of unique objects. In your case they are LocationPeople.

In .NET a collection of unique values is represented by HashSet type

In order to be used in HashSet, LocationPeople must implement equality functionality. So you need to make sure that LocationPeople do implement:

1. Equals method.
2. GetHashCode method.

In your case your objects are equal only if they have same names. 
Luckily HashSet can be used with custom EqualityComparer.

So this is what you need:

1. Implement IEqualityComparer where you define custom comparison rules
2. Use HashSet instead of List providing your custom comparer in a constructor. Here is link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503873(v=vs.110).aspx

But if you want to go for more simple solution you may want to simply declare Hashset of full names to check if full name was already added like that:

```
var usedNames = new HashSet<string>();
// inside foreach
// Hashset.Add return false if value already in hashset
if(usedNames.Add(fullName))
{
     result.Add(peopleObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

You can override the `Equals` method to compare the `FullName` property and use the `Contains` list's method:

```
//overriding the Equals method
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
{
    User user = obj as User;
    if(user == null)
        return false;

    return this.FullName == user.FullName;
}

//using the Contains method to check if you can add
if(!users.Contains(user)) 
{
    users.Add(user);
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `Contains` method uses the `Equals` method to check if the list already have an "equal" object.

So overriding the `Equals` method to implement your business rule you can use the `Contains` method easily

Anyway, if you can't use only the `FullName` property as the `Equals` implementation, you should compare each entry of the list by a `foreach` statement comparing the `FullName` property before add it.

---

### Option #2

You can use a `HashSet` to save only unique values into your "list" (now a HashSet).
Anyway, you should override the `GetHashCode` method to get the HashCode by the `FullName` property (only by the `FullName` property) and simply add you `user` instance to the `users` HashMap.

```
//overriding the GetHashCode method
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.FullName.GetHashCode();
}

//Add
HashSet<LocationPeople> users = new HashSet<LocationPeople>();
users.Add(user);
```

---

**Explanation**

The HashSet uses the HashCode to identify your entries. So if you get two objects with the same HashCode (an identical object based on the `GetHashCode` implementation), when you add this identical object the CLR know this and remove your old object and add the new object at the same position the old one was.

Both options you will never get 2x John Smith

Comment: I'd probably recommend the `HashSet` but use one of the constructors that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` so that you don't have to make a global decision about equality in the existing type. (Also, note that if you are making this global decision, it's important to override both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`)